# What is $k_B$ in the context of this question?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, thermodynamics, notation

Answering the following question

> 1000 atoms are in equilibrium at temperature T. Each atom has two
>   energy states, $E_1$ and $E_2$, where $E_2 > E_1$ . On average, there are 200
>   atoms in the higher energy state and 800 in the lower energy state.
>
> What is the Temperature?

Why is the answer $T = (E_2 - E_1)/(2 k_B ln 2)$, specifically what is $k_B$?

The original question can be found [here](http://online.physics.uiuc.edu/cgi/courses/shell/phys213/practice.pl?exam1/su11) under *Question 3*.

Comment: You already accepted an answer, so I guess the solution is clear now. However, I don't see how you get rid of $P$ and $Z$ in the formula Emilio Pisanty posted without using the fact that the partition is described by a biominal distribution and so

$\frac{p_1}{p_2}=\frac{N_1^\text{max}}{N^\text{tot}-N_1^\text{max}}=4$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The symbol $k_\textrm{B}$ pretty much invariably denotes [Boltzmann's constant](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boltzmann_constant).

Apart from that, your question is asking about the statistical mechanics fact that for a [canonical ensemble](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Canonical_ensemble) (i.e. a physical system in contact with a heat bath at some temperature $T$) the probability for the system to have energy $E$ is equal to $$P = \frac{1}{Z}e^{-E/k_\textrm{B}T}$$ where $Z$ is a normalization factor known as a [partition function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partition_function_%28statistical_mechanics%29).

Comment: Thank you for elaborating, this really puts things in perspective!